# Running v.clean tool in QGIS Python Console

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-python-console

How to use `v.clean` GRASS processing tool for break in QGIS from Python QGIS Console.
I have tried using below command:

```py
processing.runandload('grass:v.clean', layer,\ 
0,0.100000,'8132391.27018,8134827.49723,3988708.55368,3989168.7299',\
-1,0.0010,'memory','memory')
```

But it is giving me an error of `"configuring your grass, it is not configured"`.

How can I run this command from the Python console?

Comment: You can use osgeo4w shell

Comment: i am using Python console from QGIS

Comment: I don't have any problem with your command. So, is it your first time with GRASS-QGIS?

Comment: yes, it is first time.

Comment: @AhsanMukhtar - Is your GRASS configured correctly? From the menubar, go to: `Processing > Options > Providers > GRASS GIS 7 commands` and check the path. It should point to the GRASS folder inside your QGIS installation directory (e.g. for my standalone QGIS, the path is: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\grass\grass-7.0.5`)